# ROS detection Arduino

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to get an Arduino to do its tasks until ROS is connected? Once ROS is connected change its tasks. I am unable to find any way to detect ROS connection. I have seen similar questions where people are trying to figure out if ROS is connected. The common method seems to be using "ros/master" and "rosgraph", neither are usable in Arduino.

Is there a way to get Arduino to detect ROS without the above-mentioned methods?
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/397903/ros-detection-arduino/) by [bir](https://answers.ros.org/users/70699/bir/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2022-03-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can I connect an Arudino to a laptop and run it?
( I have ROS running on my laptop. )

In that case, we believe that the rosserial package can be used to achieve this.
After starting ROS, it sends a topic to Arudino indicating that it has connected to Arudino; Arudino subscribes to the topic and switches the flag in the callback.

If you switch tasks according to that flag, haven't you done what you wanted to do?

ref: https://wiki.ros.org/rosserial/Tutorials

---

Originally posted by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) with karma: 1908 on 2022-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1